# Normalised gene counts to edgeR/DESeq2?

Tags: bioinformatics, biostatistics

Both very popular differential expression packages assume a raw gene matrix count. This makes sense because the statistical model models the library depth.
But what if I normalize my counts with say, the ERCC RNA spiked-in standard? Would that affect the statistical power? False-positive? Why exactly is it not recommended to give a normalized count matrix?

Comment: This question should have edgeR and deseq2 tag, but I don't have enough reputation (require 300). Would somebody else add the tags for me?

Comment: No need for specific tags. There are hardly any DEseq/edgeR specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advice is to not generally use ERCC spike-ins at all because of variations introduced by [pipetting at the volumes they recommend](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/63339/#63340).

The thread also explains how to use DESeq and EdgeR with spike-in normalisation, with the process being easier significantly with DESeq, where you can use the calcSizeFactors on a count matrix of spike-in reads alone. With edgeR you will have to pass values using the lib.sizes parameter in the apposite functions.

If you want to use fractional counts through limma-voom should work, I think; I've had good results using voom on RSEM counts, which are fractional.